Mac OS 'Command - Tab' switch
The keybind known as 'Command + tab' for me was set to 'F3 + f4' and i had it like that for a year. but when i bought a new keyboard and tried to use 'F3 + f4' to move between apps but Mission Control would pop up instead. i know 'F3' is mission control but i dont use mission control that much and with the keys reseting my muscle memory has just vanished. i cant keep using mission control i want to use my old keybinds
